# In a LinkedList program I get an Exception saying that large string mode is engaged

Tags: c++, linked-list

here is code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;
        struct node
    {
        string program;
        node *next;
    }    

bool isEmpty(node *head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

void insertAsFirstElement(node *&head, node *&tail, string program)
{
    node *temp = new node;
    temp->program = program;
    temp->next = NULL;
    head = temp;
    tail = temp;

}

void initialize(node *&head, node *&tail, string program)
{
    if (isEmpty(head))
        insertAsFirstElement(head, tail, program);
    else
    {
        node* temp = new node;
        temp->program = program;
        temp->next = NULL;
        tail->next = temp;
        tail = temp;
    }
}

void showList(node *current)
{
    if (isEmpty(current))
        cout << "The list is empty. \n";
    else
    {
        int i = 0;
        cout << "The list contains: \n";
        while(current != NULL)
            {
                cout << current->program << " ";
                if ((i + 1) % 8 == 0)
                    cout << "\n";
                current = current->next;
                i++;
            }
    }
}
int main()
{
    node *head = NULL;
    node *tail = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 31; i++)
    {
        initialize(head, tail, "FREE");
    }
    showList(head);
    return 0;
}
```

The program has been working fine until now, but for some reason that I don't understand now when I run it it's throwing this exception "large string mode (allocated memory) is engaged"

In the show list the I included the second if statement only because it was a part of the assignment

```
bool _Large_string_engaged() const
        {   // returns whether the large string mode (allocated memory) is engaged
        return (this->_BUF_S_SIZE <= _Myres);
    }
```

This is the exception I can't figure out how to write code in the comments.

You mean all this:

```
Project4.exe!std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char> >::_Myptr() Line 1621
    Project4.exe!std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::_Inside(const char * const _Ptr) Line 3590   
    Project4.exe!std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::assign(const char * const _Ptr, const unsigned __int64 _Count) Line 2413 
    Project4.exe!std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::assign(const char * const _Ptr) Line 2430    
    Project4.exe!std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >(const char * const _Ptr) Line 1982   
>   Project4.exe!main() Line 84
```

Comment: When you run this under a debugger, where is the exception thrown? I mean, which statement throws?

Comment: `showList` may as well be in there too. And this is **all** the code (once you add `showList` to your question) that is needed to reproduce this problem?

Comment: bool _Large_string_engaged() const
  { // returns whether the large string mode (allocated memory) is engaged
  return (this->_BUF_SIZE <= _Myres);

Comment: Take a look at the call stack after the exception occurs. What statement in your program lead to the `_Large_string_engaged` call?

Comment: @WhozCraig yes it's all the code that i'm using

Comment: @GigaRohan it's the line in the main with the initialize function

Comment: This cannot possibly be all the code. There are no #include directives for standard headers, and `node` is not defined.

Comment: I'm sorry I thought you wanted only the functions

Comment: Can you include the call stack in the question?

Comment: All the code is all the code, verbatim. This is still not all the code. You cannot copy, paste, and compile it.

Comment: @Matteo What's the exception type? Examples are `std::bad_alloc` and `std::bad_cast`.

Comment: @n.m. it was all the code I just pasted it in the wrong order

Comment: It is unreasonable to expect people to reconstruct the correct order. You have code in the correct order, so please post it verbatim, it doesn't require any effort.

Comment: I don't get why the compiler throws an exception in this case. I mean we're constructing a `std::string` using a C string of only length 4 ("FREE")... I would expect that to not fail due to any buffer size related errors. Knowing the exception type would provide another clue, so it would be good if you can provide that.